# horizontal table slider in jquery mobile ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

iam developing jquery mobile ui...iam stuck as the table is not slideable horizontally in mobile,so iam able to see only few columns in mobile(say 3 out of 10 columns)....can anyone help me out??

Thank you...

This is the code:

```
    </div>`<div data-role="content" style="overflow:auto;">
            <table data-role="table"  data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow" id="myTable" style="overflow:auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="6">CustomerID</th>
      <th>CustomerName</th>
      <th data-priority="1">ContactName</th>
      <th data-priority="2">Address</th>
      <th data-priority="3">City</th>
      <th data-priority="4">PostalCode</th>
      <th data-priority="5">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Obere Str. 57</td>
      <td>Berlin</td>
      <td>12209</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Antonio Moreno Taqueria</td>
      <td>Antonio Moreno</td>
      <td>Mataderos 2312</td>
      <td>Mexico D.F.</td>
      <td>05023</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Around the Horn</td>
      <td>Thomas Hardy</td>
      <td>120 Hanover Sq.</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>WA1 1DP</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Christina Berglund</td>
      <td>Berguvsvag</td>
      <td>Lulea</td>
      <td>S-958 22</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the container div CSS to:

```
.tableCont {
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

overflow should be scroll instead of auto, and -webkit-overflow-scrolling allows mobile webkit to scroll individual dom elements.